# OR-Lambda-Layer operation with Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I'm creating a different project with Keras, it's a development of a Neural network based on predefined knowledge (described as IF-THEN rules), called Neurules. I've created a Python Module to train each one of my Neurons/Neurules from a given IF-THEN logical expression and after all I need to use Keras to create it as a network and reuse this Model.

I've already tested with one little example and it worked, everything manually added, the weights and bias. Now I've updated my script and it is giving me a JSON with all the weights to add to Keras (working until now).

Here comes my problem, I have one first Layer with 20 Neurules (neurons created from IF-THENs) but I only have 2 possible outputs, some of the Neurules/Neurons give me `output[0]` some of them the `output[1]`, I want to add a layer in-between representing the OR connections.

E.g.:

Layer 1:
NEURON1, NEURON2, NEURON3

`Output[0]` is formed by: `NEURON1 or NEURON2`

`Output[1]` is formed by: `NEURON2 or NEURON3`

What I've done in my first little example was: I've created and trained an OR neuron with my pre-developed python module and then added a second layer with it. I've then connected the entries manually to the ORs Neurules (putting the weights in the correct connections and putting 0 when they shouldn't influence the OR). Now I have something bigger and I'm automating the whole process.

Visualization of the simple net:
Buffer is just forwarding the value, OR is doing an OR operation with the inputs.

[Visualization of the layers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTFfM.png)

How can I create a Lambda Layer in Keras which takes some of the outputs, processes a logical OR and connects to one of the outputs?

I've found the Backend function: 
`tf.keras.backend.any`, but I'm not able to use it until now, how should I use it? Probably in a Lambda layer, but how?

I need to connect, for example

`(NEURON1 or NEURON4 or NEURON5)` -> `output[0]`

`(NEURON3 or NEURON6 or NEURON7)` -> `output[1]`

In my system -1 represents False and 1 represents True.
Until now I've saved which Neurons are using each one of the 2 outputs in an array in a JSON like:

```
"secondLayerDescription": [
    [0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 8, 12, 13, 14, 16, 18], 
    [2, 3, 7, 9, 10, 11, 15, 17, 19]
]
```

I hope someone can help me :)

**EDIT:** Giving an update, I found a solution after some days, I'm splitting my layer into 2 layers and operating them with lambda layers as following:

```
def logical_or_layer(x):
    """Processing an OR operation"""
    import keras.backend
    #normalized to 0,1 
    aux_array = keras.backend.sign(x)
    aux_array = keras.backend.relu(aux_array)
    # OR operation
    aux_array = keras.backend.any(aux_array)
    # casting back the True/False to 1,0
    aux_array = keras.backend.cast(aux_array, dtype='float32')

    return aux_array


#this is the input tensor
inputs = Input(shape=(inputSize,))

#this is the Neurule layer
x = Dense(neurulesQt, activation='softsign')(inputs)

#after each neuron layer, the outputs need to be put into SIGNUM (-1 or 1)
x = Lambda(signumTransform, output_shape=lambda x:x, name='signumAfterNeurules')(x)

#separating into 2 (2 possible outputs)
layer_split0 = Lambda( lambda x: x[:, :end_output0], output_shape=(11, ), name='layer_split0')(x)
layer_split1 = Lambda( lambda x: x[:, start_output1:end_output1], output_shape=(9,), name='layer_split1')(x)
#this is the OR layer
y_0 = Lambda(logical_or_layer, output_shape=(1,), name='or0')(layer_split0)
y_1 = Lambda(logical_or_layer, output_shape=(1,), name='or1')(layer_split1)
```

But I'm still having problems, I can't merge them together, I've raised a new question based on this new topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it, I need to sort my Neurules Layer, split them and then, with one Lambda Layer for each split, do some processing as shown in the EDITed part of the question: normalize the inputs, use the `backend.any` and then cast the `True` or `False` back to float.